# How do I merge .doc files?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have 500+ doc files that I need to merge in one file. How do I do that? I have tried insert --> from a text file, but it merges only like the first 50 of them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the user interface fails, I'd suggest a macro. Can you list your file names into the word document, one paragraph one name? Then the following macro will replace the file names with file content:

```
Sub Include()
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set oRange = .Paragraphs(i).Range
            sFname = oRange.Text
            sFname = Left(sFname, Len(sFname) - 1)
            sFname = "c:\tmp\" & sFname
            oRange.InsertFile FileName:=sFname
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Replace `c:\tmp\` with your path.